# Некорректно отображаются цвета на мобильных устройствах

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

Есть, к примеру layout темно (любой цвет) зеленого цвета, но на мобильных устройствах он отображается чуть светлее, чем нужно.

Думал, что монитор откалиброван не правильно, посмотрел с другого моника-всё ок.

Что сделать, чтобы цвета отображались корректно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего, это свойство дисплеев с [PenTile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PenTile_matrix_family) матрицей. У нее зеленых пикселей больше, чем остальных, поэтому цвет может искажаться.

https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/73578